# Need help figuring out the number of times 2 actors acted together in the most number of movies (cypher)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I wrote the command below to list out pairs of actors that have acted together in different movies and lists the number of times the pairs acted together.

```
match (person1)-[:ACTED_IN]->(Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(person2)
return DISTINCT Movie.title, person1.name, person2.name, count(Movie) AS pairs
ORDER BY pairs DESC
```

I feel it's inaccurate though as its counting duplicate instances, ie- `x` and `y` are being counted as one instance and `y` and `x` are being counted as a separate instance. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add some logic for this, for example :

```
MATCH (person1)-[:ACTED_IN]->(Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(person2) 
WHERE id(person1) < id(person2)
RETURN DISTINCT Movie.title, 
                person1.name, 
                person2.name, 
                count(Movie) AS pairs 
ORDER BY pairs DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

To properly see the movies that every pair of actors appeared in (in descending order of shared movies), this should work:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person)
RETURN p1.name, p2.name, COLLECT(m) AS movies, COUNT(m) AS pairs
ORDER BY pairs DESC
```

This query takes into account the fact that [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (like `COUNT` and `COLLECT`) use the non-aggregating elements in the same `WITH` or `RETURN` clause as "grouping keys". Also, `DISTINCT` is not needed, since aggregating functions implicitly return distinct rows (if there are any grouping keys).